# MarshalByRefObject vs Marshal by value in performence c#

Tags: c#, serialization, marshalling

I have big data structure that I pass between two application domains. What way of transporting do you propose `MarshalByRefObject` vs `Marshal` by value?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the two is that Marshal by value copies the entire object across application domain boundaries; with MarshalByRefObject, you are effectively sharing the object between the domains as a reference (see the [specifics on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.marshalbyrefobject.aspx)).

Therefore, if objects are large, and performance is an issue, MarshalByRefObject will probably be the best way to go.

Comment: No, MarshalByRef only simulates sharing by 'ref'. That is not physically possible. Therefore it incurs more overhead and will be slower.